# parsing a txt file and writing to 2 separate files

Tags: c, parsing

Im taking a txt file as an input and my first parsing works as intended, but im having trouble getting the logic to get the second parse.

For example: lets say the txt file looks like this:

```
.text
main:
 ...     // some instruction (assembly)
exit:
 ...     // exit instructions
.data
 ...
```

What I'm trying to do is save everything after .text to one file (text.txt, lets say) and everything after .data to another file (data.txt). The way my first parse works is it copies everything over to text.txt, then breaks out when strcmp(str, ".data\n") == 0. This works as intended, however I'm not sure how to get the second half.

At first I tried changing the body of my if(strcmp(str, ".data\n") == 0) from a break to a while hoping i could just continue using the FILE* file pointer, however this ends up not completing the execution and i have to exit my terminal.

Thanks for the help, and let me know if I need to post anything else.

```
void preprocessTextFile(FILE* file, FILE* file2, FILE* file3) {

   char str[256];
   while(!feof(file)){

    fgets(str, sizeof(str), file);
    if(strcmp(str, ".data\n") == 0){
       preprocessDataFile(file, file3);
    }

...

}

void preprocessDataFile(FILE* file, FILE* file2) {

   char str[256];
   while(!feof(file)){

    // gets rid of ".data"
    char* word = strchr(str, '.');
    if(word){
       *word = 0;
    }

    // gets rid of comments
    char* hashCom = strchr(str, '#');
    if(hashCom){
       *hashCom = 0;
    }

    char* word2 = strtok(str, ", \t\n");
    int count = 0;

    while(word2){
       fprintf(file2, "%s%s", count++ ? " " : "", word2);
       word2 = strtok(NULL, ", \t\n");
    }

    if(count){
       fprintf(file2, "\n");
    }

   }
}
```

This results in an exe that never ends in my terminal. My strategy was once it reaches .data it calls preprocessDataFile() using the pointer from the previous function (i made the assumption that it would still be pointing to .data when passed into preprocessDataFile) and then I could copy the rest of it using the same logic to the second file (data.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I feel it would be cleaner to have `preprocessDataFile` follow `preprocessTextFile`, not be called by it. Or at least place a `break` after the call to `preprocessDataFile` because when EOF is met, the iteration in the first loop (in `preprocessTextFile`) resumes until it reaches the while condition again.

**Note**: there is no `fgets` in your `preprocessDataFile` so your file is not being read anymore. That would explain why your program hangs.

**Second note**: your `// gets rid of ".data"` portion of code is working on  `str` while it is still unassigned. You should have a `fgets` just before it. But then, it would be useless as the `.data` part was read (and consumed) by the last call to `fgets` in `preprocessTextFile`

Before you updated your question my answer was: See the following example:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define strlen 256

int main(void) {
    char str[strlen];
    FILE *fin = fopen("file", "rt");
    FILE *fout1 = fopen("text", "w");
    FILE *fout2 = fopen("data", "w");
    while (fgets(str, strlen, fin) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(str, ".data\n") ) break;
        fputs(str, fout1);
    }
    do {
        fputs(str, fout2);
    } while (fgets(str, strlen, fin) != NULL) ;
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout1);
    fclose(fout2);
}
```

That gives:

```
$ gcc t.c && ./a.out 
$ cat text
.text
main:
...     // some instruction (assembly)
exit:
...     // exit instructions
$ cat data
.data
...
```

Your original question did not mention removing comments nor getting rid of the `.data` header..